# cross compiled numpy with clang depends on libgcc_s.so.1

Tags: python, numpy, clang, cross-env

I am trying to cross compile numpy for an different platform using a clang-based cross compiler toolchain. I have built a custom version of python that runs on the target platform, and trying to use crossenv make a wheel of numpy. Even though the underlying compiler that I am using is clang (both host-python and build-python) the resulting numpy seems to have an gcc dependency libgcc_s.so.1.

I have some difficulty understanding why this happens and roughly what I can do to prevent this. I believe the problem is specific to numpy- I can't disclose specifics but I have a couple of packages like cffi that I was able to successfull cross compile.

Any suggestions of what I could try to prevent from linkking gcc dependencies, I assume it just thinks its using gcc because of crossenv.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to inject configuration settings for setting native and cross compilers explictly. At the time of writing, numpy uses meson for building the relevant c/c++ modules so I explictly made relevant information for meson (https://mesonbuild.com/Cross-compilation.html), and injected the explicitly as arguments of pip in crossenv.